# How can I float text around an image in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, mobile-development

[image: An example of what I want]

How could I achieve this layout in Flutter?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, really. I was searching the docs for something that would point me in the right direction and didn't find any.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2022

Comment: Disappointing...

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2022#issuecomment-376370973
you can easily implement it like this

Comment: @UmairM Yeah, I saw that in the thread earlier. I meant it was disappointing there's nothing built in for it. Thank you! If you want, you can add it as an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: I have posted the answer and will see if I got some free time this weekend. I will implement this and let you know how it turns out :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I published package [drop_cap_text](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/drop_cap_text)  to achive DropCapText, you can also put an **image** as custom widget inside DropCap.

[image]

Comment: I'm using this package. But I have an issue: https://github.com/mtiziano/drop_cap_text/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

You can use RichText.

```
                  RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      text: TextSpan(
                        children: [
                          WidgetSpan(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              "assets/images/loyalty_icon.png",
                              width: 100,
                              height: 100,
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                "loreum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec odio nec nisl tincidunt tincidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec odio nec nisl tincidunt tincidunt.",
                            style: theme.textTheme.bodyLarge,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ))
```

Answer (score -3):

its Pretty  basic just simple Row with the data inside it

```
 Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset('Your image link here'),
      Text('you paragraph here')
    ],)
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer. This will have a fixed width and the text will also need to go flow below the image.

Comment: This only put the text beside the image. By 'float', it means we want the text to flow below the image, when it has gone past the image's height, such as what we get on the web and on microsoft word.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Stack(): https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/layout#stack

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var stack = Stack(
      alignment: const Alignment(0.6, 0.6),
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/pic.jpg'),
          radius: 100.0,
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black45,
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Mia B',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    // ...
  }
}
```

You can use a Container() widget with foregroundDecoration:

```
Container(
  child: Text('Hello World'),
  foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage('https://www.example.com/images/frame.png'),
      centerSlice: Rect.fromLTRB(270.0, 180.0, 1360.0, 730.0),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: This seems to make the text overlay the image rather than put the text to the side around the image.